# Parsing single spaces using boost::spirit parser

Tags: boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

I want to able to parse single spaces between terms (even there exist multiple single spaces) using this [parser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67198433/15469601). I tried adding the `qi::space` parser to the `character` rule like this
`` _character  = alnum | char_("\"'| !#$%&()*+,./:;>=<?@]\\^_`{}~[-") | qi::space; ``
but this doesn't even compile. How can I enforce single space parsing even if the exist multiple whitespaces.

Comment: Can you show what is "going wrong"? Because there's no reason "it" should not compile, nor not do what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

The way I look at it,

1. _character is already lexeme so skipper issues are out ([Boost spirit skipper issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17072987/boost-spirit-skipper-issues/17073965#17073965))
2. `char_("abc") | char_("d")` is equivalent char_("abcd")`
3. The expresion `char_("\"'| !#$%&()*+,./:;>=<?@]\\^_`{}~[-")`ALREADY contains the space, so tacking on`| qi::char_(' ')` would not change a thing
4. You seem to expect that `space` actually matches `' '` (ASCII 32). Which is almost true, but it matches anything your locale classifies as `isspace`. That includes (horizontal) tab, formfeed, newline and possibly others.

I think you need to rethink your problem, likely you're confused about something else

- Review [that linked post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17072987/boost-spirit-skipper-issues/17073965#17073965) to check your understanding of the skipper (which is active on rules `_rule`, `_expression` and `_list`).
- Perhaps you are seeing "multiple matched" because tabs appear as multiple spaces, and will get matched
- Perhaps you have a mistaken understanding about what the effect of changin `_character` would be: it's actually exclusively used **inside** quoted literals. It's highly unlikely that you needed to special-case space parsing inside literals.

Comment: maybe this may clarify my question; I want to be able to read the whitespace between literals, terms  or a literal and a term. For example: `<num> ::= <a> a | b b`. I want to able to read the whitespace in between.

Comment: So, why are you mucking with `_character` rule? That makes... no sense for the reason I explained in the answer. Can you post a new question, where you post the code you have, the input you want to parse and the output you want to achieve?

Comment: (Oh, and maybe also state the GOAL, why you are trying to read significance into BNF whitespace. So we don't get stuck in the next station of [X/Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem))