# Boost::spirit::qi fails to compile for a string matcher

Tags: c++, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

I'm trying to write a parser using boost::spirit::qi which will parse everything between a pair of `"` as-is, and allowing escaping of `"` characters. I.E., `"ab\n\""` should return `ab\n\"`. I've tried with the following code ([godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/ExjPjhjMf)):

```cpp
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <string>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

int main() {
    std::string input{R"("ab\n\"")"};
    std::cout << "[" << input << "]\n";

    std::string output;

    using Skipper = qi::rule<std::string::const_iterator>;
    Skipper skip = qi::space;
    qi::rule<std::string::const_iterator, std::string(), Skipper> qstring;

    qstring %= qi::lit("\"") 
        > ( *( (qi::print - qi::lit('"') - qi::lit("\\")) | (qi::char_("\\") > qi::print) ) )
                                                            //   ^^^^^
        > qi::lit("\"");

    auto success = qi::phrase_parse(input.cbegin(), input.cend(), qstring, skip, output);

     if (!success) {
        std::cout << "Failed to parse";
        return 1;
    }
    
    std::cout << "output = [" << output << "]\n";

    return 0;
}
```

This fails to compile based on some template errors,

```
/opt/compiler-explorer/libs/boost_1_81_0/boost/spirit/home/support/container.hpp:130:12: error: 'char' is not a class, struct, or union type
  130 |     struct container_value
      |            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
.....
/opt/compiler-explorer/libs/boost_1_81_0/boost/spirit/home/qi/detail/pass_container.hpp:320:66: error: no type named 'type' in 'struct boost::spirit::traits::container_value<char, void>'
  320 |             typedef typename traits::container_value<Attr>::type value_type;
```

I can get the code to compile if I change the underlined `qi::char_("\\")` with `qi::lit("\\")`, but that doesn't create an attribute for the `\` which it matches. I've also found that I can get it to compile if I create a new rule which embodies just the Kleene star, but is there a way to get boost to use the correct types in a single expression?

```cpp
qi::rule<std::string::const_iterator, std::string(), Skipper> qstring;
qi::rule<std::string::const_iterator, std::string(), Skipper> qstringbody;

qstringbody %= ( *( (qi::print - qi::lit('"') - qi::lit("\\")) | (qi::char_("\\") > qi::print) ) );
qstring %= qi::lit("\"") 
    > qstringbody
    > qi::lit("\"");
```

Comment: Not relevant to your problem, but note that **Expect** `a > b` will throw `expectation_failure` if `b` does not follow `a`, whereas **Sequence** `a >> b` will not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> qi::char_("\") with qi::lit("\"), but that doesn't create an attribute for the \ which it matches

This is what you require. Parsing should translate the input representation (syntaxis) into your meaningful representation (semantics). It **is** possible to have an AST that reflects escapes, of course, but then you would NOT be parsing into a string, but something like

```
struct char_or_escape {
      enum { hex_escape, octal_escape, C_style_char_esc, unicode_codepoint_escape, named_unicode_escape } type;
      std::variant<uint32_t, std::string> value;
};
using StringAST = std::vector<char_or_escape>;
```

Presumably, you don't want to keep the raw input (otherwise, `qi::raw[]` is your friend).

### Applying It

Here's my simplification

```
qi::rule<It, std::string(), Skipper> qstring //
    = '"' > *(qi::print - '"' - "\\" | "\\" > qi::print) > '"';
```

> Side note: It seems to require printables only. I'll remove that assumption in the following. You can, of course, reintroduce character subsets as you require.

```
qstring = '"' > *(~qi::char_("\"\\") | '\\' > qi::char_) > '"';
```

Reordering the branches removes the need to except `'\\'`, while being more expressive about intent:

```
qstring = '"' > *('\\' > qi::char_ | ~qi::char_('"')) > '"';
```

Now, from the example input I gather that you **might** require a [C-style treatment of escapes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C). May I suggest:

```
qi::symbols<char, char> c_esc;
c_esc.add("\\\\", '\\')                                                            //
    ("\\a", '\a')("\\b", '\b')("\\n", '\n')("\\f", '\f')("\\t", '\t')("\\r", '\r') //
    ("\\v", '\v')("\\0", '\0')("\\e", 0x1b)("\\'", '\'')("\\\"", '"')("\\?", 0x3f);

qstring = '"' > *(c_esc | '\\' >> qi::char_ | ~qi::char_('"')) > '"';
```

(Note some of these are redundant because they already encode into the secondary input character).

### Demo

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/55ba1e069a09320c)**

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <iomanip>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

int main() {
    using It = std::string::const_iterator;

    using Skipper = qi::space_type;
    qi::rule<It, std::string(), Skipper> qstring;

    qi::symbols<char, char> c_esc;
    c_esc.add("\\\\", '\\')                                                            //
        ("\\a", '\a')("\\b", '\b')("\\n", '\n')("\\f", '\f')("\\t", '\t')("\\r", '\r') //
        ("\\v", '\v')("\\0", '\0')("\\e", 0x1b)("\\'", '\'')("\\\"", '"')("\\?", 0x3f);

    qstring = '"' > *(c_esc | '\\' >> qi::char_ | ~qi::char_('"')) > '"';

    for (std::string input :
         {
             R"("")",
             R"("ab\n\"")",
             R"("ab\r\n\'")",
         }) //
    {
        std::string output;
        bool success = phrase_parse(input.cbegin(), input.cend(), qstring, qi::space, output);

        if (!success)
            std::cout << quoted(input) << " -> FAILED\n";
        else
            std::cout << quoted(input) << " -> " << quoted(output) << "\n";
    }
}
```

Printing

```
"\"\"" -> ""
"\"ab\\n\\\"\"" -> "ab
\""
"\"ab\\r\\n\\'\"" -> "ab
'"
```

### Further Reading

For more complete escape handling, see here: [Creating a boost::spirit::x3 parser for quoted strings with escape sequence handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61695235/creating-a-boostspiritx3-parser-for-quoted-strings-with-escape-sequence-hand/61696706#61696706) (also alternative approaches instead of the symbols).

It contains a list of even more elaborate examples (JSON style unicode escapes etc.)

Comment: For completeness, [compare `qi::raw['"' > *('\\' >> qi::char_ | ~qi::char_('"')) > '"']`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f7841d50c5865981)

Comment: I like this showing how to do this with a symbol table; I'd actually handled that case with a semantic action to handle the replacement. But my issue still stands, and is still visible in this solution-- If your string includes an escaped character which isn't in the symbol table, it simply removes the `\`. I want it to preserve that escape character.

Comment: My answer explains why you _don't_. If you want the semantic action approach, go the `qi::raw` route.

Comment: This "string" is only partially being parsed; its contents may be passed to a further downstream parser which have their own handling of escaped characters. So, yes, I do want the escape characters to remain.

Comment: And even more fundamentally for my understanding of boost spirit: if you change `qstring = '"' > *(c_esc | '\\' >> qi::char_ | ~qi::char_('"')) > '"';` to `qstring = '"' > *(c_esc | qi::char_('\\') >> qi::char_ | ~qi::char_('"')) > '"';`, it will not compile

Comment: #1 semantic action escape artist with `raw[]`: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/443539b3f8727744

Comment: #2 your fundamental understanding of spirit: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/035c4cb7f4ebc9e0 Note that `fusion::vector<T...>` is like `std::tuple<T...>`.

Comment: Thanks for the example with the semantic action which senses the type of the rule! That helps greatly!

Comment: There was another approach here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9404189/detecting-the-parameter-types-in-a-spirit-semantic-action/9405265#9405265, which is kinda a FAQ entry. However I came up with the newer way to phrase it using c++17, lambdas and also qi::copy which wasn't there at the time.